# Powershell How transfer cell value from column C to Column B , one by one

Tags: excel, powershell

I have below powershell script:

```
$NewExcelFile = "F:\test\test-data123.xlsx" 
$newExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$newwb = $newExcel.Workbooks.Open($NewExcelFile)
$sheet=$newwb.Worksheets.Item(1)
$sheet.Name = 'sheet1'
$importedExcelRows = Import-Excel $NewExcelFile 
$q=$($importedExcelRows.Count)
$q1="B"+$q 
$r1 = $sheet.Range("R2:$q1") 
$r1.cut() 
$i1="C"+$q
$r2 = $sheet.Range("I2:$i1") 
$sheet.Paste($r2)
$newwb.Close($true)
$newExcel.Quit()
```

I have below Excel:
[image]

**I want to change cell on by one like I wanna cell value like cell C2 to cell B2**

**Please find below error message Error:   **

```
Cannot convert the "OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage" value of type "OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage" to type "OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage".
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ImportExcel\7.4.0\Public\Import-Excel.ps1:122 char:17
+ ...             $ExcelPackage = New-Object -TypeName OfficeOpenXml.ExcelP ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ImportExcel\7.4.0\Public\Import-Excel.ps1:124 char:24
+                 else { $ExcelPackage.Load($stream) }
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ImportExcel\7.4.0\Public\Import-Excel.ps1:229 char:47
+ ...               if ($Path) { $stream.close(); $ExcelPackage.Dispose() }
+                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
Failed importing the Excel workbook 'F:\test\test-data1.xlsx' with worksheet '': Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ImportExcel\7.4.0\Public\Import-Excel.ps1:227 char:21
+ ...     catch { throw "Failed importing the Excel workbook '$Path' with w ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Failed importin...o a null array.:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Failed importing the Excel workbook 'F:\test\test-data1.xlsx' with worksheet '': Cannot index into a null arr 
   ay.
```

Comment: Why are you using `ComObject` if you have access to `Import-Excel`?

Comment: It's also unclear what should happen with the current values on the `current value` column

Comment: @mklement0 , this error come from $importedExcelRows = Import-Excel $NewExcelFile

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you mean by _"I want to change cell on by one like I wanna cell value like cell C2 to cell B2"_. Why not also show us what the desired result should be??

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why are you using `ComObject` having access to `Import-Excel`. If your intent is to replace the values of the `current value` column with the values of `change value` column, using `Import-Excel` you can treat it as if it were a Csv:

```
# Export a Test Xlsx

@'
no,currentVal,changeVal
1,a1,b1
2,a2,b2
3,a3,b3
4,a4,b4
5,a5,b5
6,a6,b6
'@ |
ConvertFrom-Csv |
Export-Excel ./test.xlsx -WorksheetName example

# Import it
$xlsx = Import-Excel ./test.xlsx -WorksheetName example

# Replace the Values
$xlsx | ForEach-Object {
    $_.currentVal = $_.changeVal
}

# Save the new Xlsx
$xlsx | Export-Excel ./test2.xlsx -WorksheetName example2
```

This would be the result of the above operation, still, it's unclear to me what should happen with the "replaced values" of `current value` column and what should happen with the `change value` column after performing the operation.

```
no currentVal changeVal
-- ---------- ---------
 1 b1         b1
 2 b2         b2
 3 b3         b3
 4 b4         b4
 5 b5         b5
 6 b6         b6
```

Comment: Thanks for response my question , but I have already data instead of this a1,b1
2,a2,b2
3,a3,b3
4,a4,b4
5,a5,b5
6,a6,b6

Comment: @Nilam sorry but I don't understand what you mean, it's not clear enough what you're trying to accomplish.